# java+Imagen impresora termica EPSON TMT20

Tags: java, imagen, impresora, epson

Hola necesito su ayuda para poder imprimir desde código java, en un ticket de una impresora térmica EPSON TMT20 una imagen, que no es mas que un código QR del negocio.
paso código ejemplo de generación e impresión de ticket.

```
public void getCamposfijos() {
        Propiedades prop = new Propiedades();
        nombre = prop.getConfPROPIEDADES("nombre");
        dir = prop.getConfPROPIEDADES("direccion");
        gracias = prop.getConfPROPIEDADES("gracias");
        
        cabecera =   "  "+nombre+" \n"
                         +  "   "+dir+"\n\n"
                         +  "  PEDIDO: \n"
                         + linea + "\n";        
        
    }

/*armado de un ticket de ejemplo que funciona perfecto por cierto.
necesito meter una imagen *.jpg en la impresión.*/

public void p() {
        try {
            /** ARMO TEXTO FIJO */          
            getCamposfijos();           
            
            PrinterService printerService = new PrinterService();

            String impresion = cabecera+ "\n"
                            + concatena("(1) x Milaneza con frita", "$ 250,00",puntos)+"\n"
                            + concatena("(1) x muzarela", "$ 200,00",puntos)+"\n"
                            + concatena("(1) x 1/2 tarta jamon y queso", "$ 180,00",puntos)+"\n"
                            + concatena("(1) x Milaneza con frita", "$ 250,00",puntos)+"\n"
                            + concatena("ENVIO", "$ 30,00",puntos) +"\n"
                            + concatena("","TOTAL: $910,00",espacios)+"\n\n"
                            + linea + "\n"
                            + "DESC. EXTRA: Para las 21:30hs \n\n"
                            + "Cliente: MOE \n"
                            + "Direccion: AV. SIEMPRE VIVAS \n\n"
                            + gracias + "\n"
                            + " fecha: "+Util.getFecha(new Date(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")+"hs \n\n\n"
                            + " N° Ticket: 532 \n\n\n";
            
            printerService.printString(getDefaultPrinter(), impresion);

            // cut that paper!
            byte[] cutP = new byte[] { 0x1d, 'V', 1 };

            printerService.printBytes(getDefaultPrinter(), cutP);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Mensajes.ERROR(" * NO SE ENCUENTRA LA IMPRESORA: "+getDefaultPrinter()+"\n"+e.getMessage());
        }       
    }
```

Lo que quiero es meter dentro del ticket arriba, abajo, o donde sea un código QR, que lo tengo en un jpg en por ej: c:/sistema/qr.jpg, o puedo ponerlo dentro de la carpeta del proyecto. pero bueno, tiene una ubicación puntual.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

logre que salga la imagen, pero termina de imprimirla y me corta el ticket.
y lo que necesito que a continuación de esta imagen impresa, continué con el ticket en cuestión.
código impresión imagen.

```
/*imprime una imagen en la impresora predefinida.*/
    public static void printIMG() {
        try {
            PrintService ps = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
            DocPrintJob job = ps.createPrintJob();
            DocFlavor DF = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.JPEG;
            FileInputStream FIS = new FileInputStream("C:/SistResto/qr.jpeg");
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(FIS, DF, null);
            PrintRequestAttributeSet attrib = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
//          attrib.add(new Copies(1));  
//          job.print(doc, attrib);
            job.print(doc, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

con ese framgneto de codigo imprime una imagen, pero cuando hago por ej:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Printer.printIMG();
        Printer.p();

    }
```

imprime la imagen, corta el papel, y luego imprime el texto.
Alguien me puede orientar como hacer para que no realice ese corte o bien que pueda enviar todo junto a imprimir y haga un solo corte?
gracias.